# += operator adding unexpected 'ff' byte to string in c++

Tags: c++, string, codeblocks

I have this code:

```
#include<iostream>
void test(string in){
    for(short i=0; i<in.length(); i++)
        cout<<hex<<(unsigned short)in[i];
    cout<<"\n";
    string msg=in;
    for(short i=0; i<msg.length(); i++)
        cout<<hex<<(unsigned short)msg[i];
    cout<<"\n";
    msg+=(char)128;
    for(short i=0; i<msg.length(); i++)
        cout<<hex<<(unsigned short)msg[i];
}
int main(){
    test("123456");
}
```

I expect the output to be:

```
313233343536
313233343536
31323334353680
```

But instead, it is the following:

```
313233343536
313233343536
313233343536ff80
```

It's clear that the += operator does something that i didn't count with. I use Code::Blocks on a 64-bit machine. How can I fix it?

Comment: I'm not sure why you think `+=` is the issue here. I assume you didn't choose `128` by accident. What happens if you change that value? What happens if you just assign `(char)128` to an int?

Comment: Sign extension.  `unsigned short` is 2 bytes on your platform and the leading zero's are not being printed.  When sign extending `signed` `128` (`char` is probably signed on your platform) to `unsigned short` you get `ff80` and as the leading digits are not `0` they get printed.

Comment: [Is char signed or unsigned by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2054939/is-char-signed-or-unsigned-by-default)

Comment: @cigien I chose 128 because I need one '1' bit first and then '0'-s

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your compiler uses an signed `char` type, i.e. the range of values is `[-128, 127]`.

```
msg+=(char)128;
```

adds a char with value `-128` which is represented binary `0b1000'0000`.

When you read this char in `(unsigned short)msg[i]`, the value first undergoes a promotion padding the value with 1 bits until the width of the target type is reached and then the conversion to `unsigned short` happens leaving you with (`0b1111'1111'1000'0000` = `0xff80`)

```
0b1111'1111'1000'0000
  ^^^^ ^^^^           bits from sign extension
            ^^^^ ^^^^ 128
```

To fix this you can cast to `unsigned char` first:

```
for (short i = 0; i < msg.length(); i++)
    cout << hex << static_cast<unsigned short>(static_cast<unsigned char>(msg[i]));
```

Comment: I see the problem. Forgot the last conversion.

Comment: I see that now. I just missed the printing coversion.